# Как указать диапазон значений для [nargs] в [argparse.add_argument]?

Tags: python, argparse

Можно ли указать в аргументе nargs что-то вроде "не более 2" или "от 2 до 7", чтобы на вход можно было подать список до 2(или от 2 до 7) аргументов, и как это сделать?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Input resize arguments')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-wh', '--width_height', type=int, nargs='<2', default=[0,0], help='Width and Heigth of image')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [решением от @unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4195302/5741205).

если посмотреть [как реализованы Action функции в `argparse`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/argparse.py#L838-L870), то можно создать свой `Action` класс по их образу:

```
import argparse

def required_length(nmin,nmax):
    class RequiredLength(argparse.Action):
        def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
            if not nmin<=len(values)<=nmax:
                msg='argument "{f}" requires between {nmin} and {nmax} arguments'.format(
                    f=self.dest,nmin=nmin,nmax=nmax)
                raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
    return RequiredLength

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Input resize arguments')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-wh', '--width_height', type=int,
                   nargs='+', action=required_length(2,7),
                   help='Width and Heigth of image')
```

Тест:

```
In [130]: parser.parse_args('-wh 1'.split())
...
skipped
...
ArgumentTypeError: argument "width_height" requires between 2 and 7 arguments

In [132]: parser.parse_args('-wh 1 2 3'.split())
Out[132]: Namespace(width_height=[1, 2, 3])
```

PS не забудьте [поблагодарить](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) автора ответа - @unutbu
;-)

Comment: а можно разжевать?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets как я понял смысл в том, что напрямую диапазоны указывать нельзя, но можно прикрутить такую вещь как выше: длина списка значений сравнивается с минимально и максимально возможными, которые указываются в аргументе action. Если количество аргументов не подходит - вызывается исключение и кастомное сообщение пользователю. Про собственный экшн [тут](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action)

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, надеюсь так стало немного понятнее...